# Xcode Run IBAction when app loads

Tags: objective-c, xcode, window, ibaction

I would like to hide a window before the app has loaded. Now I know to hide a window you can use this;

```
[window2 orderOut:nil];
```

which works fine when you click on a button but what if I wont it to be hidden before or whilst the application has loaded?

So sorta need an IBAction on when the application loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Interface Builder, you can uncheck the box (in the window's attributes pane) that says to show the window at startup.

Or you can put that line of code in your app delegate's `applicationWillFinishLaunching` (or perhaps `applicationDidFinishLaunching`) method. (Might not work in the first one, I'm not sure.)

But I'd go with the first option, personally.

Comment: thanks I should have checked interface builder before I posted :P, I found the option before you answered but thanks for the code :)